# Flutter Charts using Charts from iOS with cocoapods

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there any way to use the native chart libraries from android and iOS in flutter?

I've looked at the docs of flutter and they provide a possibility to use native code, but you only can pass strings, ints, and so on.

There is currently no beautiful usable UI library for charts in Flutter. I've only found https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_charts, but it doesn't look good.

Anyone had a way to create a wrapper for UI?

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/dart-flitter/flutter_webview_plugin should work as example how to use native UI widgets.

Comment: thanks, maybe it works, but this is full screen, isn't it?

Comment: No, you can specify an area where it should be rendered. There seems to be a problem still to have it scroll with other content.

Comment: ok, thanks, I will test this out :-)

Comment: I don't know what you don't like about the current libraries, but it might also be useful to try things yourself, it is easier than I am used to from Android. This is a very nice tutorial to building graphs with flutter (see also part 2): https://medium.com/flutter-io/zero-to-one-with-flutter-43b13fd7b354

Comment: the library is really outdated and make it myself needs to long, it is for an small mock project. a line chart is not that hard. thanks for the link, had already read it

Comment: @Rene the current libraries are limited to certain kind of needs. Just an example, multi-touch is missing. That’s why you might need the native charts.

Comment: The question is already pretty old, but @Yatko you can always embed native views in Flutter, so if you have a nice native view you can use that as well. https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-platformview-how-to-create-flutter-widgets-from-native-views-366e378115b6